# Powershell Comparison Operators not functioning when trying to compare vs command output

Tags: .net, powershell

I am new to powershell scripting so, sorry if I'm doing something obviously wrong.

Here is the bit of the script that is not working:

```
$PrinterList= Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_Printer |Select-Object Name
$SelectedPrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"

if( $Printerlist -NotContains $SelectedPrinter ){[void][System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Failure!")}
Else{[void][System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("success")}
```

Here is the output of $PrinterList on my computer:

OneNote
Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Microsoft Print to PDF
Fax

As you can see $SelectedPrinter should be contained in $PrinterList but when I run the script it returns as if it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if($Printerlist.Name -NotContains $SelectedPrinter){}`

Or leave `if($Printerlist -NotContains $SelectedPrinter){}`

and change to `$PrinterList = (Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_Printer |Select-Object Name).Name`